# ANTLR with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: antlr, visual-studio-2013

Is it possible to use ANTLR with Visual Studio 2013?

I installed [ANTLR language support](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/25b991db-befd-441b-b23b-bb5f8d07ee9f), which says it is for VS 2010 and 2012.  And when I install the ANTLR 4 NUGET package into a VS 2012 project, then right-click the project and select add new item, a bunch of ANTLR-related file types come up in the menu -- ANTLR4 Combined Grammar, and so forth.  But when I do the same thing in VS 2013, the ANTLR-related file types do not appear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [ANTLR 4 NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Antlr4) and the [ANTLR Language Support](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/25b991db-befd-441b-b23b-bb5f8d07ee9f) extension are two completely independent products (neither depends on the other, although they are most often used together).

The ANTLR 4 NuGet package does not depend on any specific version of Visual Studio, so it works fine with Visual Studio 2013. As of today, the ANTLR Language Support extension has been released for Visual Studio 2010 through Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: The ANTLR Language Support extensions now supports 2013 out of the box as of version 1.2